# How to generate phone numbers with itertools

Tags: python, linux, permutation, python-itertools

I want to generate a file of all possible phone numbers with itertools.

```
from itertools import permutations
perm = list(permutations(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'],7))
prefix = ['071','070','076','077','075']
file_to_write = open("numbers.txt",'w')
for pre in prefix:
    for per in perm:
        per = ''.join(per)
        file_to_write.write(pre+per+"\n")


file_to_write.close()`
```

this gives me a huge list of numbers but some numbers are missing because this cannot use one number twice in a combination as an example the list has not the item '0713025693' because the number three is repeated. What can I do. Please Help me.

Comment: Use `itertools.product`

Comment: Please read the description of the tags that you applied! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `permutations`, which does not allow duplicates, instead use `product`.  In this case, you want:

```
from itertools import product

product(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'], repeat=7)
```

or, as Boris points out, you can pass a string rather than a list (since strings are iterables), e.g.

```
product('1234567890', repeat=7)
```

Or you can `import string` and use:

```
product(string.digits, repeat=7)
```

For any of these, you could pass the result to `list` to produce a list, but it would be very long.  It's preferable to leave it as an iterator, using it to iterate through the values without actually storing them in a list.  Just beware that, as an iterator, if may only be traversed once, so if multiple passes are needed, you will need to recreate it.

Comment: You can just do `”0123456789”` or `string.digits`instead of a list

Comment: @Boris Good point, thankis.  I updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

use `itertools.product` (cartesian product) instead:

```
from itertools import product
list(product('ab', (0,1,2)))

[('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: In the interest of future readers coming from google searches, you should answer the question in the title, not just point him in the right direction